# como hago para Mostrar pagina luego de que ésta está completamente cargada mi response ajax e

Tags: ajax

este es mi codigo, el bucle while carga 78 input tipo img y hasta que se carguen todas las imagenes da una sensacion desagradable al lado del cliente y muy lenta quisiera una opcion para que sea mas rapida y asi poder dar una mejor experiencia de carga de todas las imagenes. ayudemen porfavor, muchas gracias

php
     include ("conexion_bd.php");

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tarot ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 78");




while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $cartaNombre = $row["Carta"];

    echo "<input type='image' src='$cartaNombre' value='$cartaNombre' alt='no se encuentra' width='7%' class='cartas' name='carta' onclick='this.disabled = true; valor(value)'>";

}

mysqli_free_result($result);



mysqli_close($con);
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../modelo/lectura_baraja.php",
        success: function(response)
        {
            $('.baraja').html(response).fadeIn();
        }

   });

   });
```

html

Title

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js_global/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/lectura.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

```
<div id="mesa">

    <div class="baraja">

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/lecturaResponse_ajax.js"></script>

    </div>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/lectura.js"></script>

    <button onclick="myFunction(ESEAadn)">enviar</button>

    <div class="respuesta"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hola que tal buenas tardes, solo queria ver si te entendi bien, lo que tu quieres es saber en que momento todas las imagenes ya se descargaron? para asi poder mostrarlas cierto? ahora estas usando un input por algun motivo en especial? y el src es una URL o base64?

Comment: hola gracias por escribir si justamente eso quiero mostrar las imagenes cuando ya esten cargadas, si uso input para mandar el value, pero ahora que me haces pensar no se si un tag img puede tener value creeo que si se puede seria mas facil con imagen. nesesito alvergar una value para luego poder madarlo como formulario y el src es una variable consulta de la base de datos . si puedes ayudarme muchas gracias

Comment: pues en el onclick podrias mandar valor('$cartaNombre') si usas un img y en los img pudes usar algo como esto:

$('img').load(function() {
        $('div').show(); //muestra el div despues de que la imagen carga.
 });

Comment: es una gran idea, gracias

Comment: investigue como hacer que img lleve la variable atraves de la funcion pero no me funciona si tu sabes podrias explicarme por favor. gracias y disculpa por quitarte tiempo. muchas gracis

Comment: como lo estas haciendo? la manera correcta seria algo asi:

    echo "<input type='image' src='$cartaNombre' onclick='this.disabled = true; valor(\"$cartaNombre\")'>";